# Syntax for arara on texwork with preamble.tex as input file to be used for generating many different documents

Tags: texworks, arara

I installed arara on windows and it is working properly as noted by running it from cmd shell. 
Is putting follwing syntax in  a "template" preamble that I use as input file to generate multiple documents adequate to compile the document or I have to mention filename everytime in each tex file. I am using texwork.

How can I make texwork automatically build the file as the file is changed ?

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: clean: { files: [ *.aux, *.bbl ] }
% arara: clean: { files: [ *.bcf, *.cod ] } 
% arara: clean: { files: [ *.blg, *.lof ] }
% arara: clean: { files: [ *.lot, *.out ] } 
% arara: clean: { files: [ *.toc, *.log ] }
```

Comment: The arara syntax % arara: pdflatex failed to work if you put it in a input preamble.tex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule, called `remove` from `Paulo Cereda`:

```
!config
# Clean rule for arara
# author: Paulo Cereda
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: remove
name: Remove
command: <arara> @{remove}
arguments:
- identifier: remove
  default: <arara> @{isNotEmpty(item, isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f").concat(' "').concat(getBasename(file))concat('.').concat(item).concat('"'))}
```

This deletes by

`% arara: remove: { items: [ aux , toc , bbl ] }`

the files `jobname.aux` and `jobname.toc` and `jobname.bbl`.

If you want to delete files like `*.aux` and `*.toc` and `*.bbl` with any names, try this tiny changing:

```
!config
# Clean rule for arara
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: removex
name: RemoveX
command: <arara> @{removex}
arguments:
- identifier: removex
  default: <arara> @{isNotEmpty(item, isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f").concat(' "').concat('*')concat('.').concat(item).concat('"'))}
```

This deletes by

`% arara: removex: {items: [ png , tmp ] }`

all files with the extension `*.png` and `*.tmp`.